# Passing arguments to initialize a Singleton

Tags: swift, singleton

I'm trying to create a user singleton that gets initialized with a users username, email, and user ID every time the user logs in or registers.

I have something like this going but I'm not sure what to do with the `static let sharedInstance`:

```
class UserSingle {

    var userName: String
    var email: String
    var userID: Int
    static let sharedInstance = UserSingle()   


    private init(userName: String, email: String, userID: Int){
        self.userName = userName
        self.email = email
        self.userID = userID
    }

}
```

I'd like to use the values from the dictionary below to use as the parameters to initialize the singleton.

```
userInfo = ["username": "fake name", "email": "fake email", "userID": 1]
```

As of now I'm getting an error for `sharedInstance` because its calling `UserSingle()` without the necessary arguments for the initializer.  How do I get around this since I don't have the user data yet?

Comment: Where do you actually want to create the instance at, and how do you want to set that user as the current user (instead of just a user)?

Comment: @Wain once the dictionary is returned from the login process is when I want to create the user singleton.  I'm not creating multiple user singletons - Just one for the current user and thats it.

Answer (score 3):

One way to create a singleton with the given properties is by using a function that will return a Singleton with the details filled in.

```
class UserSingle {

        var userName: String
        var email: String
        var userID: Int
        static let sharedInstance = UserSingle()

        private static func sharedInstanceWith(userName:String, email:String, userID: Int) -> UserSingle {
            let instance = UserSingle.sharedInstance
            instance.userName = userName
            instance.email = email
            instance.userID = userID
            return instance
        }

        private init(userName: String = "" , email: String = "", userID: Int = 0){
            self.userName = userName
            self.email = email
            self.userID = userID
        }

    }

    let user1 = UserSingle.sharedInstance
    let user2 = UserSingle.sharedInstanceWith("BJ", email: "xyz@gmail.com", userID: 12)
    user1.userID  //12
```

I couldn't make this work with a rather beautiful approach like so. This actually will not be a singleton as with every `sharedInstance` call a new object is being created.

```
static let sharedInstance: (String, String, Int) -> UserSingle = {
    name, email , id in
    return UserSingle(userName: name, email: email, userID: id)
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution.  I'll try it out.  Quick question, is `private init` what makes a singleton a singleton.  I have a version working that has no initializer.

Comment: @brosef ```static let sharedInstance=UserSingle()``` is what makes a singleton. ```private init(``` enforces the caller to use Singleton rather than allowing to create a new object.

Comment: I see.  As long as I don't try to create new objects, then it shouldn't be a problem right?  As of now, if I completely remove the init, I can get a user singleton and access it from all viewcontrollers.

Comment: You got it. @Brosef

Comment: @kandelvijaya: as you said this is not a singleton.

Comment: I don't think that this would work.  The private sharedInstanceWith function cannot be called from outside the class.